# Template overloading (reference and non reference version)

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have a seemingly simple question that I don't know how to solve.

Imagine the following template method

```
template<typename T> void Add(T& var);
```

where the specializations can Add something to a container (sort of). I can pass in `POD` or more complicated types like `strings` and that is why I'm passing T as a reference.

The problem with this is that whenever I want to call Add(...) with a result of another method like:

```
Add(MethodThatReturnsAnInt());
```

This won't work and a temporary variable is needed to hold the result of `MethodThatReturnsAnInt()`.

Is there any way of overloading `Add` so that I can have a reference passing and non reference passing version?

```
template<typename T> void Add(T& var);
template<typename T> void Add(T var);
```

would `std::enable_if` be of any use in this situation?

Comment: Read and learn about [rvalue references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Comment: Google _forwarding reference_. Your situation and the resulting question were so common that they added a language feature for it. ;-) It's a fundamental feature of C++11 and probably answered enough times already.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? What does `Add()` do?

Comment: Is there any reason why you pass a reference instead of const reference? You can bind a const reference to temporaries so it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a C++11 compiler, you could use a <s>[(Universal Reference)](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)</s> *forwarding reference*:

```
template<typename T> void Add(T&& var) {}

int MethodThatReturnsAnInt() { return 42; }

int main()
{
    int a = MethodThatReturnsAnInt();

    Add(a);                        // lvalue passed: void Add(int& var) takes lvalue reference  
    Add(MethodThatReturnsAnInt()); // rvalue passed: void Add(int&& var) takes rvalue reference  
}
```

`T&&` is not a *rvalue reference* in this example. In a type-deducing context `T&&` has a special meaning. `T` depends on the expression passed to the function `Add()` as follows:

- If the expression is an **lvalue** (eg: `a`) of type `E`, then T is deduced to `E&`.
- If the expression is an **rvalue** (eg: value returned by a function) of type `E`, then T is deduced to `E` and `var` will have the type `E&&`.

Comment: How does this differ from what @SamVarshavchik said (apart for the fact that you are using the old-fashioned name _universal reference_)? Also, the example looks somehow wrong and misleading.

Comment: The second call is actually `Add(int&& var)`, not `Add(int var)`. It might be the same for `int`, but not for more complex class.

Comment: @skypjack sam name dropped a term you could use to google and solve the problem using help elsewhere.  Sergji posted an answer that solves the problem here.

Comment: @Yakk I usually try to suggest how to integrate an answer or invite the _sam_ to do that instead of creating a new answer that mostly copies the other. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler does not already support C++11, you will need to update your compiler, and then use a forwarding reference, `&&`.